# list isn't loading in panel in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to load a `List` in a `Panel` but i am getting following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined
```

here is my `ProfileContainer.js` which contains the `List`

```
Ext.define('demo.view.ProfileContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'profilecontainer',
   // requires: [ 'Ext.TitleBar', 'demo.view.ProfileList' ],
    requires: [ 'Ext.TitleBar' ],
    config: {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'demo',
            cls: 'bms-bg'
        }, {
            xtype: 'profilelist'
        }]
    }
});
```

here is the code of `ProfileList.js`

```
Ext.define('demo.view.ProfileList', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    alias: 'widget.profilelist',
    requires: ['demo.store.ProfileStore'],
    config: {
        store: 'ProfileStore',
        itemTpl: '{name}',
    }
});
```

here is my `ProfileStore.js`

```
Ext.define('demo.store.ProfileStore',{

    extend:'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'demo.model.ProfileModel',
        data:[

            { name: 'John Rambo' },
            { name: 'Brad Pitt'}

        ]
    }
});
```

and `ProfileModel.js`

```
Ext.define('demo.model.ProfileModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [

            { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
        ]
    }
});
```

but my list isnt loading into panel and i am getting above mentioned error

Answer (score 0):

xtypes are alias defined as `widget`

So you need to define them like:

```
alias:'widget.profilecontainer',
```

or

```
alias:'widget.profilelist',
```

---

Some information on `require` and `uses`:

You have dependencies between your classes which need to be resolved. This is normally done by the buildtool or if you don't run it by yourself.

Dependencies are one of the reasons why you use `require` or `uses` where `require` can be threated as *strict* because it ensure that the class is there as soon as it get required

> *And here comes a the difference: because this is not valid if you lazy load. At this time the required class will be available after the
>   class is defined. The build tool cleans this up places the required
>   classes before the class definition*

while `uses` can be treated as *lose* because it only ensure that the class exist the time the `Ext.onReady` get called.

Normally this wan't give you headache but if the class definition requires that dependencies get resolved at definition time it will blow up when lacy loaded. If you now the dependency (xtype) that is causing this you can try to load it manually by using

```
Ext.require('class');
```

which need to get placed before the class definition.

Comment: i have defined `alias:'widget.profilelist'` in `ProfileList.js` and i am using it as `xtype:'profilelist'` in `ProfileContainer.js` but still getting the same error

Comment: @Hunt please extend your question with the new code snippets.

Comment: @sra Actually all you need in ST2 is `xtype: 'my-xtype'`, it works the same as `alias: 'widget.my-xtype'` does in ExtJS 4.

Comment: i have changed the code , but as i said if i use xtype or alias its not loading giving me the same error

Comment: @kevhender Thanks for that hint. I am not that used to ST. I still can't understand how these two frameworks from the same company are so different. At least the core should match.

Comment: @sra after ur suggestion i am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'deprecate' of undefined` error

Comment: @Hunt Yeah, my fault. These frameworks are still so damn different... But I think your problem is, that the xtype you are referring to has not been loaded. Have you build the project before testing?

Comment: is there any need to build , as i have added all the reference in `app.js` and i m refreshing the page , i guess that will be enough , rite ?

Comment: @sra when i replace the path in `app.json` by `path: "../touch/sencha-touch-debug.js` its working fine so i think u r right as when it is `secha-touch.js` its in a production mode which requires build